# Find files in order in sorted folders

Tags: bash, find

I have directories listed as

```
01  02   03_rev  04_N  .....  154  155
```

I want `find` to look for a file in (numerical order of folders) sorted folders as listed above, How can I modify below find command?

```
for f in $(find . -name 'log_*.log'); do
    ....
done
```

---

Thanks

Comment: So you want to loop through the directories in numerical order, then try to find a file within each directory named in the pattern `log_*.log`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should be recursive.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `find`, you can just use shell globbing, you would get the files sorted by natural numeric order:

```
for f in [0-9]*; do echo "$f"; ## Do stuffs; done
```

**Example:**

```
$ for f in [0-9]*; do echo "$f"; done
01
02
03_rev
04_N
154
155
```

---

**Answer based on comment:**

If you want to search for a file in these directories, recursively and then read the file if found, do:

Rather than looping over each directory separately, you should go to their parent directory and let `find` traverse on these directories only (use globbing), and search for the file:

```
find /parent/[0-9]* -type f -name 'file.txt'
```

To read the content of the file(s):

```
find /parent/[0-9]* -type f -name 'file.txt' -exec cat {} +
```

Assuming the parent directory of these directories is `/parent`, and the file you are searching for is `file.txt`.

Comment: But I am looking for a file in these folders recursively, and if it exists I want to access few lines from it.

Comment: @RaziAhmed Check my edits.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just the last one, can we redirect find to traverse on these directories in order as listed with 'ls' command?

Comment: @RaziAhmed `find` will follow the natural numeric order with filename expansion done by shell on `/parent/[0-9]*`. Do `ls /parent/[0-9]*`, and check. Also why you want this? You are traversing every directory anyway.

Comment: It work on current parent directory, but I want to make it general and include it in my .zshrc file. In future, I might have directories starting with alphabets or so.

Comment: @RaziAhmed I don't see why you would need any order for that. Just make a relevant function, and put that in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Another thing is that, I want to grep last 2 columns of last line from each matched file. And I am using awk to print each line with specific color. It makes easy on my eyes to analyze output. Thats why I was using loop because I need to initialize variable inside loop  to generate output in various colors.